# Finding the integral variables

Tags: calculus

> Is it okay to say, for example, $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{x^2}{x^3+1}dt$ if $t$ is a function of $x$?

I was doing a trig substitution for a trig problem and I had intermediate steps where I had something like that but someone told me I can't say that since the integral means $x$ is independent of $t$. I thought I could because $t$ is a function of $x$.

For a more concrete example, let $x = \sin(t)$. I said $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2}dx = \int \dfrac{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(t)}}{\sin^2(t)}dx$. Is this valid?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform substitution but you can't ignore the meaning of the differential symbol $dx$ and $dt$ so by letting:

$$x = \sin(t)$$

you must calculate:

$$dx = \cos(t) \,dt$$
so that:

$$\int \dfrac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2} \, dx$$

becomes

$$\int \dfrac{\sqrt{1-\sin^2(t)}}{\sin^2(t)} \cos(t) \, dt.$$

The general concept is generally discussed under 'Integration by substitution'. You can read more about it here [integration-by-substitution](http://www.mathportal.org/calculus/integration-techniques/integration-by-substitution.php).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with that, but of course you must keep track of the distinction between $dt$ and $dx$.  The sort of thing you mention is done routinely in things like this:
$$
\int \arctan x\,dx = \underbrace{\ \int u\,dx = xu - \int x\,du}_\text{integration by parts} = x\arctan x - \int x \frac{dx}{1+x^2}= \text{etc.}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your favourite definition of the integral.

At worst it constitutes a mild abuse of notation to indicate that the integrand is multiplied by the derivative of the function.

At best it is part of the definition, see "Riemann-Stieltjes integral".